# hit db connection only once in php

Tags: php, database, oracle, config

i have a web application with oracle database , i have included my database configuration file in each and every pages on top of the file.

config.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$con = oci_connect("cp_user","log","ORCL");
if (!$con)
{
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```

so in each pages i have included my config file.

now my problem is when each page loads it hits the login.

my question is there any option to login(hit) only once in index page loads , in remaining pages connection should be in open condition but without login again , and also should able to execute queries , until i close the connection.

my question may be silly but i need to know whether its possible or not.

any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use require_once of php

Comment: I would put all the connection information in one file called config.php and then use `require_once('/path/of/config.php');` at the top of each file instead. But that's me. Also be sure to close your connection on each use or at end of file. Don't want your connection to stay alive.

Comment: @JoshuaNightingale i am also doing the same exactly what you do,  again in all the pages it hits the login credentials which is there in config file. i don't want to login again and again in all the pages, it should hit the login credentials only once in index.php file.

Comment: @aldrin27 , ya i agree with you , but the thing is again which hits the login,i don't want to login again and again in all the pages, it should hit the login credentials only once in index.php file

Comment: Use [oci_pconnect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-pconnect.php) instead of [oci_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) to create a persistent connection to your database server.

Comment: @mario.klump do i need to include the same in each every page ?

Comment: You just have to replace `oci_connect` with `oci_pconnect` in your config.php. Please read the documentation of `oci_pconnect` and the following doc about persistent database connections: http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: @mario.klump , thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace [oci_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-pconnect.php) with [oci_pconnect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) in your config.php to create a persistent connection to your database server.

Please also read the documentation of `oci_pconnect` and the documentation about [persistent database connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)